# Is there a useful inhabitant for the type `forall v. Int -> v -> IO v`?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Let's say we want to write a generic property map backed by IO operations,
but for some reason we are required to make the value type polymorphic.

```
type Key = Int
get:: Key -> v -> IO v -- Takes a key and a default value, return the associated value
put:: Key -> v -> IO () -- store (Key,v) pair doing some IO
```

Do Free Theorems require that `get` and `put` do only trivial things in this case too,
and if so, can we cheat the ghc's type system to implement a real type-indexed
IO database?

Comment: No, we absolutely cannot, even if we are allowed to cheat the type system, execute any assembly code and pretend it has the type we need. In practical down-to-earth terms, `put` gets a pointer. It has no information whatsoever about the pointed-to data stucture, and thus no way to store it.

Comment: Oh, actually `put` can store the pointer itself. Of course this is not really backed by any IO operations, and when the program terminates, the stored values disappear. One only needs to take care of the garbage collector (mark any pointer that is stored as uncollectable, unmark when deleted from the storage).

Comment: Thanks, well, I'm actually glad to hear that, and I have absolutely no desire to do this myself. I just asked this because I've seen a type in a monadic package that seemed 'too polymorphic' for my usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, strange things may happen in `IO`, so I do not think that there is a rigorous notion of Free Theorems involving `IO`. Anyways, from what I know about `IO` as it is implemented, assuming the functions do

1. nothing that can crash (such as doing pointless pointer arithmetic to produce a value of type v),
2. not use any of the unsafe functions (which generally break any Free Theorems-like reasoning),
3. do not return bottom (e.g. `undefined` or an exception) and
4. do eventually “return”

then the “returned” value will be the parameter.

But this means that it is *not* possible to implement a type-indexed database using `IO`.

It would be possible with a `Typeable a` constraint. In that case, the expected Free Theorem does not hold and a `get` function would be allowed to return something else than the default value.

Comment: Thanks, is there an example of formal proofs of this kind involving (a restricted set of) IO?